# Contour detection of bone on medical image with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, medical-imaging

I have this medical image (slice of knee bone). I would like to make a nice clean contour of the bone with OpenCV. I have tried so many things, but the bone edges are so blurry and noisy on some parts, I just couldn't get it clean.

Can you please help me? How would you do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhCTp.png)

I was trying different thresholdings, blurring, morphological operations.
I'm aiming for a contour of the bone as binary image, either filled or simple line.

Comment: When you ask a question like this, show your code, so we can see what you tried and what is not good enough. You also must show what the expected output is. Most people on here don’t have any experience looking at CAT scans, and won’t know which part is the bone.

Answer (score 0):

I think that doing a simple closure solves the problem:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('your_image')
img = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# binarization 0 becomes black, [1,255] becomes white.
thresh = cv.threshold(img, 1, 255,cv.THRESH_BINARY )[1] 
# closure
kernel_square = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(15,15))
closure = cv.morphologyEx(thresh,cv.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel_square)
# plot
plt.imshow(closure,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[result 1](https://imgur.com/nKJPmGs)

Then you can find countours via the cv.findCountours or if you want a simple countour you can find the gradient by doing a dilation.

```py
import numpy as np

kernel_square2 = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(3,3))
dil_clo = cv.dilate(closure,kernel_square2)
out = np.bitwise_and(dil_clo,~closure)

plt.imshow(out,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[result 2](https://imgur.com/LaIc6mB)

edit: If you want just the bone you can use OTSU binarization. Then just change the kernel size.

```py
thresh = cv.threshold(img, 0, 255,cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU )[1]
```

edit2:just the bone

```py
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('/content/jhCTp.png')
img = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# binarization 0 becomes black, [1,255] becomes white.
thresh = cv.threshold(img, 0, 255,cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU )[1]
# closure
kernel_square = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(30,30))
closure = cv.morphologyEx(thresh,cv.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel_square)
# plot
plt.imshow(closure,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don’t think that’s the bone. The question is not posed clearly, there is no indication of what the expected output is, so I won’t blame you. But you should really not answer questions that are not clear and unambiguous. You’ll just be wasting your time.

Comment: Sure, you are right. I was just trying to help... i'm new here. But if he wants the bone he can change the binarization method, using otsu's, then a simple closure also gives the bone.

thresh = cv.threshold(img, 0, 255,cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU )[1]

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault, I don't have much experience in posting questions here. Yes, the contour you gave first is the skin. The bone is the lighter part inside.

Comment: Se if the edit2 part helps you.